# Matplotlib RegularPolyCollection with static (data like) sizes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to create a RegularPolyCollection with static sizes?

I'd like to give the size in data units, not in screen units. Just like the offsetts.

The target is to have an image of a camera with 1440 hexagonal Pixels with a diameter of 9.5 mm.

It is possible to achieve this with looping over 1440 Polygons but i was not successfull creating it with a PolyCollection which has big advantages, for creating colormaps etc.

Here is the code i use to plot the 1440 hexagons with static size:

```
for c, x, y in zip(pixel_color, pixel_x, pixel_y):
    ax.add_artist(
        RegularPolygon(
            xy=(x, y),
            numVertices=6,
            radius=4.75,
            orientation=0.,
            facecolor=c,
            edgecolor=edgecolor,
            linewidth=1.5,
        )
    )
```

And this code produces the same but with wrong and not static (in terms of data) sizes:

```
a = 1/np.sqrt(3) * 9.5

collection = RegularPolyCollection(
    numsides=6,
    rotation=0.,   
    sizes=np.ones(1440)*np.pi*a**2,  # tarea of the surrounding circle
    facecolors=pixel_colors,
    edgecolors="g",
    linewidth=np.ones(1440)*1.5,
    offsets=np.transpose([pixel_x, pixel_y]),
    transOffset=self.transData,
)

self.add_collection(collection)
```

How can I achieve the static sizes of the hexagons with the advantages of having a collection?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem. The solution is to simply use `PatchCollection` instead of `RegularPolyCollection`. The disadvantage is, however, that you have instantiate every single patch manually. Below you'll find a code example that plots 10,000 regular hexagons on a regular grid.

```
# imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import RegularPolygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

# set up figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

# positions
pixel_x, pixel_y = np.indices((100, 100))
pixel_color = np.random.random_sample(30000).reshape(10000, 3)
dx = 4    # horizontal stride
dy = 5    # vertical stride 

# set static radius
poly_radius = 2.5

# list to hold patches
patch_list = []

# creat the patches
for c, x, y in zip(pixel_color, pixel_x.flat, pixel_y.flat):    
    patch_list.append(
            RegularPolygon(
                    xy=(x*dy, y*dy),
                    numVertices=6,
                    radius=poly_radius,
                    orientation=0.,
                    facecolor=c,
                    edgecolor='k'  
            )
    )


pc = PatchCollection(patch_list, match_original=True)
ax.add_collection(pc)

ax.axis([-3, 480, -3, 480])
plt.show()
```

On my machine this code takes about 2.8 seconds to render everything.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use `RegularPolyCollection`, I've figured out how to set the sizes correctly. The main limitation is that the sizes depend on the axes transform, and so both the axes limits and the figure size need to be locked in *before* you calculate the sizes.

In the version below, the figure - and axis - also has to be square.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sin60 = np.sin(np.pi/3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 8)
ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.set_xlim(-1.5*sin60, +1.5*sin60)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5*sin60, +1.5*sin60)
ax.set_frame_on(False)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

coords = [[-1/2, +sin60/2], [+1/2, +sin60/2], [0, -sin60/2]]

radius = .5/sin60
data_to_pixels = ax.transData.get_matrix()[0, 0]
pixels_to_points = 1/fig.get_dpi()*72.
size = np.pi*(data_to_pixels*pixels_to_points*radius)**2

hexes = mpl.collections.RegularPolyCollection(
                numsides=6, 
                sizes=3*(size,),
                offsets=coords, 
                edgecolors=3*('k',), 
                linewidths=1, 
                transOffset=ax.transData)

ax.add_collection(hexes)
```

[image]